# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when binding datatable to datagridview in c #

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, datagridview, datatable

I Want to save multiple value from  window form to **datatable**  and then  i bind this table to **Datagridview**. Value are adding in `Datatable` but At:

```
dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.Table);
```

binding point error shows

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How Can I solve it?

```
public AddOrder(string ItemName,int Qty,Double Price)
    {


        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id");
            dt.Columns.Add("Item Name");

            dt.Columns.Add("Qty");
            dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price");
            dt.Columns.Add("Amounts");


            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] = a;
            a++;

            dr["Item Name"] = ItemName;
            dr["Qty"] = Qty;
            dr["Unit Price"] = Price;
            dr["Amounts"] = (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Qty"]) * Convert.ToInt32(dr["Unit Price"]));
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.Table;

        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            DevComponents.DotNetBar.MessageBoxEx.Show(ee.Message,"Error Message");
        }
    }
```

Comment: have u tried dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: Yes  I Use  dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: The Null reference question this question was linked to as a duplicate is too general. The question is really why could binding to a datagridview generate a null reference exception.

Answer (score 2):

The object reference exception could be occurring in an event handler related to data binding. For example, let's say your datagrid has something like this in the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
```

When you call `GridView1.DataBind()`, the `GridView1_RowDataBound` method executes for each row during the data bind process. This method could contain some bad code to give you the "object reference..." exception.

Answer (score 1):

is the initialization of the **dataGridViewX1** in a InitializeComponent method?

```
    I Think it is parameterized constructor I it does not has initialization of controls
```

1) solution

```
   InitializeComponent(); need to call this method.
```

Its working my application

Answer (score 0):

Directly assign `data table` to `gridview`:

```
dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;
```

instead of:

```
dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView.Table;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i this code (dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;) but still same problem

Comment: Update your question with the stack trace of exception

Answer (score 0):

Place a break point and check either you have value in

```
- dr["Qty"] = Qty;

 - dr["Unit Price"] = Price;
```

Most probably one of them or both has empty value.

or try this and check

```
 - dr["Qty"] = 3;

  - dr["Unit Price"] = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply i  this code (dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;)  but still same problem

Comment: One record is exist in dt,  but when i bind it ti datagridviewx1  then it cause the   error   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as is with the way you bind.

I have made it work by defining missing variable (a):

```
    AddOrder("something", 2, 100);  
    ...
    //assign some default value since the PO did not define the variable at all...
    int a=0;
```

Now, you are adviced specify datatypes for columns like this:

```
        dt.Columns.Add("Qty",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Unit Price",typeof(Decimal));
        dt.Columns.Add("Amounts",typeof(Decimal));
```

Also, if you are planning to edit data then after you protect the Amount, you should use an expression with the column as follows:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(Decimal), "Qty *[Unit Price]");
```

Update:

Assuming the error occurs at the bind, try this:

```
dataGridViewX1.DataSource = null;
dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: What problem? Please give specific error. Do you get an exception? What is the exception message?

Comment: exception message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: this is strange, try to see update in answer...Also, do a debug trace and see if dt is null or not before the bind.

Comment: Yes   dear Method  and datagridview are  on  the form

Comment: dt is not null it has one record

Comment: This is very strange. I almost can't imagine that you get a bind error this way. Maybe you are not using standard datagridview component...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindDataGrid()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // Insert code to populate a DataTable with data. 

    // Bind grid to DataTable.
    dataGrid1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

`dataGridViewX1.DataSource = dt;`

insert break point to view the dt value.

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused because you are trying to access a property of an object that is null.

Whenever you get this sort of error, you can try to step through and debug your source code.
This will help you get to the line that is throwing the error.

You can take a look at which object is null and then fix this error by figuring out why this object is null in your code.